# Increase number of nodes defining polygon for correct projection

Tags: r, r-sf, qgis

I have an issue when making a map with R using `sf`. I need to use a LAEA projection (CRS 3035), but one of my horizontal line is straight whereas it should be curved (the one in the middle):
[image]

I understand that the issue comes from the way I have created my custom polygon in QGIS: my straight line is only defined by two points whereas it should have a multitude of nodes such as the left side of the polygon:
[image]

But how do I do that? I've been looking for a solution for an hour, but I can't seem to find the correct keywords to achieve this. Is there a tool to densify my line?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sf::st_segmentize()` to add points, though it might get bit tricky -- coordinate system is taken into account, so for lines that follow parallels, latitude values will not remain constant (check the example bellow how `Y` is changing).

When segmentizing a shape without CRS, coordinates work as on a Cartesian plane. Not sure if there's a more elegant approach to this, but first clearing  CRS, then segementizing and finally resetting CRS should get you covered.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

# create shape, set CRS
sh_wgs84 <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -40, ymin = 40, xmax = 0, ymax = 70), crs = "WGS84") |> st_as_sfc()
sh_wgs84 |> st_coordinates()
#>        X  Y L1 L2
#> [1,] -40 40  1  1
#> [2,]   0 40  1  1
#> [3,]   0 70  1  1
#> [4,] -40 70  1  1
#> [5,] -40 40  1  1

# segmentize shape with CRS
sh_wgs84_seg <- sh_wgs84  %>%  st_segmentize(units::set_units(600, nautical_mile))
sh_wgs84_seg |> st_coordinates()
#>                X        Y L1 L2
#>  [1,] -40.000000 40.00000  1  1
#>  [2,] -30.134586 41.31607  1  1
#>  [3,] -20.000000 41.76330  1  1
#>  [4,]  -9.865414 41.31607  1  1
#>  [5,]   0.000000 40.00000  1  1
#>  [6,]   0.000000 47.50000  1  1
#>  [7,]   0.000000 55.00000  1  1
#>  [8,]   0.000000 62.50000  1  1
#>  [9,]   0.000000 70.00000  1  1
#> [10,] -20.000000 71.11828  1  1
#> [11,] -40.000000 70.00000  1  1
#> [12,] -40.000000 62.50000  1  1
#> [13,] -40.000000 55.00000  1  1
#> [14,] -40.000000 47.50000  1  1
#> [15,] -40.000000 40.00000  1  1

# first remove CRS, then segmentize and set CRS
sh_seg_wgs84 <- sh_wgs84 %>% st_set_crs(value =  NA) %>% st_segmentize(10) |> st_set_crs("WGS84")
sh_seg_wgs84 |> st_coordinates()
#>         X  Y L1 L2
#>  [1,] -40 40  1  1
#>  [2,] -30 40  1  1
#>  [3,] -20 40  1  1
#>  [4,] -10 40  1  1
#>  [5,]   0 40  1  1
#>  [6,]   0 50  1  1
#>  [7,]   0 60  1  1
#>  [8,]   0 70  1  1
#>  [9,] -10 70  1  1
#> [10,] -20 70  1  1
#> [11,] -30 70  1  1
#> [12,] -40 70  1  1
#> [13,] -40 60  1  1
#> [14,] -40 50  1  1
#> [15,] -40 40  1  1

# limits for visualization
lims <- st_transform(sh_wgs84, 3035) |> st_bbox()
World <- rnaturalearth::ne_coastline(returnclass = "sf")

p1 <- sh_wgs84_seg |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = World, linewidth = .2) +
  geom_sf(fill = "lightblue", alpha = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = st_cast(sh_wgs84_seg, "POINT")) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3035, 
           xlim = c(lims$xmin, lims$xmax), 
           ylim = c(lims$ymin, lims$ymax)) +
  labs(title = "segmentize shape with CRS") +
  theme_bw() 

p2 <- sh_seg_wgs84 |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = World, linewidth = .2) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gold", alpha = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = st_cast(sh_seg_wgs84, "POINT")) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3035, 
           xlim = c(lims$xmin, lims$xmax), 
           ylim = c(lims$ymin, lims$ymax)) +
  labs(title = "first remove CRS, \nthen segmentize and set CRS") +
  theme_bw()

patchwork::wrap_plots(p1 , p2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>